# PHP getting values from one form to another

Tags: javascript, php, html

loginform.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
<font size="12px"><label><b>USER ID:</b></label><span id="tab6"></span>
<input type="text" name="t1"  title="Enter The Station Id" maxlength="5">
```

newform.php

```
<input type="text" value="<?php $_POST["t1"]; ?>">
```

i want to get the value of the userid textbox in `logingorm.php` and display the content in the textbox in `newform.php`
i have added some validations so i don't want to use `action="newform.php"` is there any other way to get the values from one form to another.

Comment: You can use javascript to post a form.

Comment: change value= "<?php echo $_POST["t1"]; ?>"

Comment: use GET method , or store into cookie... etc

Comment: how to use javascript to post values can you send me some examples

Comment: cant use GET method also i have used some validations

Comment: if i change as you sed @soni8010 i will get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When form is submitted then in loginform.php write following code..

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST))
{
    $t1 = $_POST['t1'];
    $_SESSION['t1'] = $t1;
}
```

Here I have set a session variable t1. Then we can use this session variable anywhere. I am using this t1 in newform.php.

```
    session_start();
$t1 = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['t1']))
{
    $t1 = $_SESSION['t1'];
}
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $t1; ?>">
```

Comment: It is another alternative. You should use !empty($_SESSION['t1']) because it is possible that t1 is null. upvoted :-)

Comment: sanjay chaudari if i click back then tha text box 1 is empty is there any way i can post back the values from newform.php to loginform.php

Comment: @R.shashank First, You have to reset or empty the t1 session variable value and set the value of t1 variable with your newform.php textbox. OR you can set the new session variable for newform.php 's textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give form action:-

```
<form action="newform.php" method="post">
<font size="12px"><label><b>USER ID:</b></label><span id="tab6"></span>
<input type="text" name="t1"  title="Enter The Station Id" maxlength="5">
```

in newform.php you have to echo value

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["t1"]; ?>">
```

> If action is set to "" the form submits to itself. That is, if your
>   script is index.php, your form submits to index.php.

instead you may submit your from using jquery

```
$("#form-id").submit()
```

and again using javascript you can do.

```
document.getElementById("form-id").submit()
```

Comment: i don't know jquery can you send me any examples

Comment: You may refer jquery here https://api.jquery.com/ and for submit using jquery you may refer https://api.jquery.com/submit/